# parse xml with multiple rowtags using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing, databricks

I want to parser xml using spark so I am using spark databricks lib. sample xml is as follows:

```
<Transactions>
        <Transaction>                
                <transid>1111</transid>                
        </Transaction>  
        <Transaction>                
                <transid>2222</transid>                
        </Transaction>      
</Transactions>
<Payments>
    <Payment>
        <Id>123</Id>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <Id>456</Id>
    </Payment>
</Payments>
```

code to parse:

```
val transNestedDF = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","Transactions").load("trans_nested.xml")

transNestedDF.registerTempTable("TransNestedTbl")

sqlContext.sql("select Transaction[0].transid from TransNestedTbl").collect()
```

Here I don't have any root tag also I can't define multiple row tags so if I have to process both transactions and payments in single read using above single dataframe then how to achieve that?

need help.

Comment: Can you use python libraries to handle this?

Comment: if its tough in scala then python i can try

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know scala, but it can probably be done with python or xpath/xquery expressions.

Comment: ok can u show some sample code for python to handle above scenario .. I can try

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: for every transaction we need to populate each payment id in flat file format
1111|123<newline>
1111|456<newline>
2222|123<newline>
2222|456

Comment: To make sure: each of the two pay IDs (`123` and `456`) is repeated twice: once under transid `1111` and again under transid `2222`?

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this with lxml, a python library, which itself uses xpath:

If you don't have it installed, you need to:

```
pip intall lxml
```

then:

```
import lxml.html

pay = """ [your code above]  """

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(pay)
tid =doc.xpath('Transactions//transid'.lower()) #or ('//Transactions//transid'.lower()) depending on the structure of the original doc
pid = doc.xpath('Payments//id'.lower()) #same comment

final = ''
for i in tid:
    for p in pid:            
        final = final+i.text+'|'+p.text+' \n'

print(final)
```

Output:

```
1111|123 
1111|456 
2222|123 
2222|456
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in one read, if there is no tag around both of these. If there is any common parent tag, you can use that as `rowTag` and ignore the rest that is parsed.

You can of course read them separately into two DataFrames. That works fine if you treat them separately. But you lose the association between transactions and payments, unless you can join on some ID.

But then I'd wonder why the XML structure doesn't have *any* common parent if these are associated.